# invalid operator < while sorting std::list

Tags: c++, list, exception, sorting, stl

I have a std::list graph edges and i want to sort the edges based on their destination outdegree and then their indegree. But i am getting  getting exception of invalid operator < during my comparison function below is my code. My list contains the pointers to the edges and 
edges have destination nodes as their member.

```
bool compareEdges(const Edge  *e1,const Edge *e2){
if(e1->destination->outdegree < e2->destination->outdegree){
    return true;
}
else if(e1->destination->outdegree > e2->destination->outdegree){
    return false;
}
else if(e1->destination->indegree > e2->destination->indegree){
        return false;
    }
return true;
```

}

And here is the call to the sort function.

```
currentNode->edgeList.sort(compareEdges);
```

Please help me in removing this exception.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `(currentNode->edgeList).sort(compareEdges);` helps ?

Comment: What are the types of `outdegree` and `indegree`?

Comment: What's the type of `outdegree` ??

Comment: Could you post the datatype of outdegree? Or even better the Edge data structure?

Comment: What is outdegree, what is indegree? Are you really getting an exception or just a Compiler error. Post the exact error you get, please.

Comment: outgegree and indegree are of types unsigned int. The compiler is not very description it says "Expression:invalid expression <"

Comment: Out degreea nd indegee are of type unsigned int. Its actually a failed assertion which says this     Expression:invalid operator <

Comment: Here is my complete Node and edge data structure                 struct Node{

  //Nodes are the edges and are 
  //stored as a red black tree...
  Node():id(0),indegree(0),outdegree(0),hasCycle(false),
  parent(0),edgeList(0){//edgeRoot(0),edgeTail(0),
  }

  unsigned int id;
  unsigned int indegree;
  unsigned outdegree;
  bool hasCycle;
  Node *parent;
  std::list<Edge *>edgeList;
  //Edge *edgeRoot;
  //Edge *edgeTail;
  
};

struct Edge{

  Edge():destination(0),next(0){
  }
  Node *destination;
  Edge *next;

};

Comment: `Post the exact error you get, please` <- this

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your comparator returns `true` when both relevant fields are equal. This is invalid, so it may well be what the `sort` implementation has detected via assert.

You're supposed to pass a "less than" predicate to `sort`: formally a "strict weak order". Anything else is undefined behavior. It seems in this case you got lucky, and the implementation detects that it has got into an impossible situation due to inconsistent comparisons.

Comment: What does sort have to do if two things are equal in my opinion it just needs a return true or false value. Can you please elaborate a little bit more how it should be if want to sort the edges first on the basics of outdegree and if they are same then on the basics of indegree.

Comment: It must return `false` when they're equal, I'm afraid your opinion doesn't enter into it ;-) The comparator should behave like "less than", and `x < x` is false. If you want to know the precise requirements, look up the definition of a "strict weak order".

Comment: So did u mean that i should not return any thing when two values are equal?

Comment: @AbdulSamad, it's just that you end up with `a < b` and `b < a` both true.

Comment: @Abdul: no, I don't mean that you shouldn't return anything. I mean what I said, return `false`.

Comment: `else if(e1->destination->indegree >= e2->destination->indegree)` - This greater-or-equal modification should turn it into a valid comparator. You really can't sort something if `a` should go both before and after `b` (`a<b && b<a == true`)