# overloading operators for struct as map key

Tags: c++

Hi I'm having problems overloading the operator of my struct for use as a key. Here is my struct which I intend to use as a map key, basically it has 2 char arrays:

```
struct FConfig
{
    char product[3];
    char exchange[4];
    bool operator < (const FConfig &rhs) const
    {
        return (strcmp(product, rhs.product) < 0 || 
                 strcmp(exchange, rhs.exchange <0));
    }
};
```

My comparison is as long as one of product or exchange does not equal to the rhs's, then the key is considered unique. I use this and I get "invalid operator <" during runtime. I'm totally new at creating keys, so I'm still having some trouble understanding the logic when overwriting the < operator. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532224/invalid-operator-while-sorting-stdlist

Comment: If you supply an < operator to your class, it has to behave like one while using `std` routines. I guess, that your operator is not transitive - you may find three values of FConfig, such that A < B, B < C, but !(A < C).

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion about how `operator <` should work is pretty common.  You want it to look like this:

```
bool operator < (const FConfig &rhs) const
{
   int product_comparision = strcmp(product,rhs.product);
   if (product_comparision<0) return true;
   if (product_comparision>0) return false;
   return strcmp(exchange,rhs.exchange)<0;
}
```

Since `product` is your primary key,  the only time you even consider the secondary key is if the primary key values are equal.

Comment: If those were proper strings, you could do `return std::make_pair(product, exchange) < std::make_pair(rhs.product, rhs.exchange);` (or `std::tie`).

Comment: Yes it's quite confusing to me, as when designing keys, I just think whether or not they will be equal, not 'less than'. Your solution and explanation solved my problem. Thanks a lot Vaughn :)